# Delay wordpress comment form post with jQuery to allow analytics to send tracking.

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, google-analytics

I am trying to put a custom event on my Wordpress comments form and would like to track an event every time someone clicks the submit button. The problem I am having is the form submits and creates a page request and the Google analytics code doesn't have time to work.

I need to delay the the form submit so the tracking has time to work. I have looked up similar problems and tried various solutions but cant seem to get them to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows, with my attempt to delay the form unsuccessfully.

```
<form id="commentsForm" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-      post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

<!-- Delay form submit to allow GA code to send -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#commentsForm').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds
});
}); 
</script>

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><? php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>"  title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>

<?php else : ?>

<p class="textfield">
<input name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author); ?>"  size="22" tabindex="1" type="text" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?>>

<label for="author"><small>Name <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label>   </p>

<p class="textfield"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_email); ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?>>
<label for="email"><small>Mail (will not be published) <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label></p>

<p class="textfield"><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_url); ?>" size="22" tabindex="3">
<label for="url"><small>Website</small></label></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<!--<p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> You can use these tags: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p>-->

<p class="text-area"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="58" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>

//Submit button
<p><input class="submitButton" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Comment','Submit', URL]);" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="" />


<?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
</p>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

</form>
```

I think it might not work as the form is a PHP form, but I'm not sure the best way to get it working.

Thanks for any help or thoughts.

Comment: Your example works for me. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: Well I can either get the form to submit, but not trigger the GA code (as it loads the wp-comments-post.php too quickly), or i can get it so the code submits the GA event but doesn't submit the form. In the example above the form submits, but it does it as soon as the submit button is clicked unfortunately, meaning the GA event doesn't have time to sned the custom event. Thanks for having a look at it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having issues of the order in which the submit `onclick` is firing and the `form.submit()` event fires.  Could you try pulling the click event off of your submit button and just placing it in your submit function?

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#commentsForm').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Comment','Submit', URL]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds
});
});
```

Also, maybe I missed it in your example, but what is `URL`?

Comment: Thatnks for your response. The URL variable is the URL of the page located in my Header using var URL= location.href. Probably should have included that. 

I tried your method, and it allows the custom event to take place, but in the console I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function. This stops the form submitting, and doesn't work anymore unfortunately. I will post up an example later on today, I need to mirror the site externally. I'm confused as to why the submit wont delay.

Comment: Horray! I solved it using a combination of your solution and another solution found on another thread (which I cant seem to link to, will post in the solution). I used your code and changed my submit button to <input class="submitButton" name="submitChange" type="submit" id="submitChange" tabindex="5" value="" />, changing the name and the ID. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So does my answer get the check?  Glad I could help

Comment: Yeh sorry. I forgot to check it. Thanks again for your help. Stack Overflow saves the day again!